# How to extract one combination of two elements in a cell once a time

Tags: matlab, cell-array

I want to extract one row at a time from a txt.file as follows in Matlab.

```
            29,Downstairs,9481262431000,3.79,8.2,5.6252036;
            29,Downstairs,9481312266000,2.96,7.08,4.1814466;
            13,Walking,1047162303000,-2.41,5.18,1.5390993;
            13,Walking,1047212260000,-0.3,1.73,-0.50395286;
            13,Walking,1047262309000,1.27,11.03,2.5606253;
            13,Walking,1047312266000,-1.42,14.75,8.158588;
            14,Jogging,60423222332000,13.82,-4.37,12.64;
            14,Jogging,60423272319000,14.33,7.08,-2.3;
            14,Jogging,60423322338000,19.42,19.46,-7.59;
```

This is a portion of the whole file. I need to extract every combination that the first two columns can have. For example, I extract all the rows containing

```
29,Downstairs
```

Then

```
13,Walking
```

Then

```
14,Jogging
```

and so on.

Is there a easy way to express all the combination I want to traverse? Because The `txt.file` is huge. It contains `36*6=216` different combinations(the first column containing number from `1 to 36`, second column containing 6 activities). And I want to store the rows sharing the same combination (usually one combination has more than 500 different entries, not like the example 29,Downstairs only 2) into a cell structure.

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have all your data in a file called myFile.txt, then:

```
fid = fopen('myFile.txt');
A = textscan(fid,'%s');
fclose(fid);
lines = A{1};
allInstances = cell(length(lines),1);
for i = 1:length(lines)
   temp = textscan(lines{i}, '%s', 'delimiter', ',');
   allInstances{i} = [temp{1}{1}, ',',temp{1}{2}];
end

uniqueCombos = unique(allInstances)
```

Result:

```
uniqueCombos = 

'13,Walking'
'14,Jogging'
'29,Downstairs'
```

Comment: Thank you @JCKaz. But it's not quite like what I need. Actually I need to store the rows which share the same combination into one cell, and in this case I will have 216 different cells, each containing a couple hundred of rows.